# Do i make an egg when i want to deploy a python script with custom imports to a new host machine?

Tags: python, pip

Kind of new to python.  I have been working through some development and have been working on some scripts in pycharm.  Anyways, I have been doing a lot of custom installs on my local machine leveraging things like pythoncom, or pyHook.  Those may not be on my target machine so instead of just running the python script, I am thinking I should turn it into an egg file that i just run on the machine instead?

I figure it would just do what a jar does and builds all the imports etc into the egg so it is self contained and will run correctly.

Is that true?  Is that the best course of action?   I was tempted to do something like `npm install` but for python, though a lot of things within my defined modules arent really found in pip but instead on sourceforge.

How would I best do this approach?  Is making an egg the way I am suppose to do it, or will I want to build some sort requred structure (sort of like a packages.json file for npm and then just run that when I clone a repo)?

I was hoping to do it all by way of a repo, but i dont know what the python development / distribution standard is.

Comment: This seems way too broad for an SO Q&A, but if you want to package up your code for easy installation, have a look at e.g. http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/, https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: i think it is really a 2-pronged component.   I want to be able to use github to set up the developmet environment, but i am thinking that if i want to package up all the imports specific to my machine, i would want to leverage eggs